# how to access only specific days of close from history in pinescript

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

how to access only specific days of close from history in pinescript
for ex: filter/get all close prices for all fridays only from entire history
another ex scenario: filter/get all close prices for all fridays & its next mondays from entire history.
Thanks
Sai

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `request.security()` function to extract only the values from the daily chart and collect Friday's closing prices into an array, for example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Friday closes")

dailyClose = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", close)

var array<float> fridayCloses = array.new<float>()
var float lastFridayClose = 0

if ta.change(dailyClose) and dayofweek == 6
    fridayCloses.unshift(dailyClose)
    lastFridayClose := fridayCloses.get(0)

plot(lastFridayClose, style = plot.style_stepline)
```